# Opening a second Window from MainWindow following MVVM and loose coupling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inversion-of-control

At first: This App and Question is for learning purpose

I'm on a new application and facing the problem that I want to open a Window when the user clicks on a Button in the MainView. In the past I'd have designed a Command which just creates the new Window and displays it

```
new RelayCommand((x)=>new SecondWindow().Show());
```

Now with this new Project I'm trying to fully decouple all classes from each other. To achieve this my App consists of 4 Assemblies (BL, COM, DAL and UI).
As in each WPF Application, the App starts with the MainWindow.xaml. The MainWindow.cs will create it's instance of MainWindowViewModel:

```
public ViewModel VM {get; private set;}
public class MainWindow(){
    VM = new ViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

(which already violates loose coupling) (Any tips on how to make it better?)

My last attempt is to create an instance of my second Window inside my main window

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SecondWindow x:Key="sw"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and pass it as a CommandParameter to my Command

```
CommandParameter="{StaticResource sw}"/>

new RelayCommand((x)=> ((Window)x).Show());
```

This solution works but has one big disadvantage - the second window get's created immediately after the app starts - and so does it's ViewModel which starts some heavy processes (DB Connections etc.)

I've heard something abour IoC principle but I really don't know how to use it with an wpf application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking along the right lines.... you basically have to create a List of ViewModels as your application starts up, then you can switch between them as the user presses buttons and pass the name of the ViewModel as a CommandParameter to your Command handler....

You might find this link to Rachel Lim's Blog

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Also, I'm not going to post any code here coz it simply gets too complicated. So here is a download to just about the simplest example I could come up with

http://www.mediafire.com/download/3bubiq7s6xw7i73/Navigation1.rar

Download and un-RAR it (with win RAR) You will need to step though the code, figure out what its doing and how its doing it then modify it to suit your needs... Or modify your needs to suit the code.....

The example is a modification of Rachel Lim example. It simply contains Views and ViewModels, there are no Models or data. It demonstrates switching between two different Views.

UPDATE 1

With specific reference to the demo code.... Your VMs are added to a static collection of VMs (see AddViewModel function), each View ( the DataTemplate associates View with ViewModel) is selected when you click a button for example, by calling 'SelectViewCommand' which in turn sets Current_ViewModel to the selected ViewModel... the corrisponding ContentControl is then updated to display that currently selected View...

I know is confusing and very difficult to explain

When you press a button to 'change Views' you are actually changing the value of the property that your ContentControl is bound to, so you have to call the correct SelectViewCommand in the SAME instance of the class that your ContentControl is bound too...

In the demo you'll see that in the 'LogOn_View' I call

```
 Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, ElementName=Base_V}"CommandParameter="Main_ViewModel"
```

Here I am calling the SelectViewCommand in the Base_ViewModel (x:Name="Base_V" in Base_View XAML), That's because I want to change the View that is displayed in the Base_View's 'ContentControl'

In Main_View I call

```
 Command="{Binding SelectViewCommand}" CommandParameter="MainV1_ViewModel"
```

Here I am calling the SelectViewCommand in the Main_ViewModel, That's because I want to change the View displayed in the MainView's 'ContentControl'....

Comment: So if I understood this right I should separate my MainView from the rest of my UI project and use it's viewmodel to host all other ViewModels? I'll try this but at first glance it does not seem like the solution I'm looking for. To be honest I'm a little bit confused because at some points I'm not quiet sure in which project (UI, BL, COM etc.) to store my classes - so My UI projects needs references to BL and COM.

Comment: Okay I had a look at it and now I'm really confused. I've got several VM's (lets assume 2). Each VM got a View. In my MainView I define how a specific VM has to be displayed (DataTemplate). But in the given example I don't see how my second Window could access it's VM's Properties (Binding). In the example a Button is just bound to a "SaveProductCommand" - but how does the View know that the SaveProductCommand is located inside the ProductsViewModel instead of the ApplicationViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a WindowService class for managing window changes/dialogs in MVVM.  Having "View" code in the ViewModel (i.e. Window.Show()) goes against MVVM principles.  For example:

```
public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public void ShowDialog<T>(ViewModelBase viewModel) where T : IApplicationDialog
    {
        IApplicationDialog dialog = (IApplicationDialog)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

And then your call from the ViewModel would look something like:

```
windowService.ShowDialog<SecondWindow>(new SecondWindowViewModel());
```

If you're using DI, you can pass a reference to the IoC container to the window service and create the window instances from that rather than using Activator.CreateInstance (i prefer the DI approach personally)